# Maven repositories

Tags: maven-3

We are using maven in the development process. Maven provides a nice feature of configuring the repositories. Using this feature I have created a **remote internal repository** and I can download the dependencies from that repository. 
The development machines are pointing to this **remote internal repository**. Each development machine has its own **local repository(~/.m2/repository/)** and hence the dependencies of the project are downloaded from the **remote internal repositor**y to the **local repository(~/.m2/repository/)** on each  developer machine.

**Is there any way that the local repository(~/.m2/repository/) on developer machines can be set to the internal remote repository that we have created and which is used for downloading the dependencies from.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If take a look on [Maven Introduction to Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) first paragraph says:

`There are strictly only two types of repositories: local and remote.`

There is no way how you could change this behavior.

If you would handle that differently it would cause many problems. E.g. build would take much longer because of  downloading file all files, IDE would work not work properly (project dependencies would not be stored local), ...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest another approach to share dependencies and artifacts. In our projects we use [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) as a proxy and repository for our artifacts. It works well with no issues. A basic configuration I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919010/maven-download-files-from-one-plugin-from-different-repositories/7925801#7925801).

After nexus is running you could also setup continous integration using [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and enjoy a fully automated environment.

Comment: hi stacker! Thanks for the suggestion about using Nexus. Right now I am trying to learn more about the maven features and once i get to know about the maven basics I will surely integrate nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Is your requirement to avoid each developer from having to download all dependencies to his local repository?

Assuming your **remote internal repository** has the same format as a maven local repository, you can achieve this by adding the following  line in the `settings.xml` of all your developers.

```
<localRepository>shared-drive-location-of-remote-repository</localRepository>
```

Comment: Hi Raghuram. Yes you are correct and should have specified the purpose that i was looking for. Thanks for the info, I will implement it and come back to you regarding this.